# How can I see the standard output of a Java task?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a java program to run and it will print out some messages on the console. When I put the program as an Ant java task, I can't see my output on the console. What should I do?

I should add that I run Ant from Eclipse. The console output does not appear in Eclipse console.

Answer (score 2):

Ant's java task does not block the standard output of a Java application unless you've configured the `output` attribute. Can you show what's in your build file? I suspect it's either you wrote the build file wrongly or executed Ant wrongly. Please explain *how* you tried running your application and whether or not your application prints output to console if run via `java` on the command line.

Comment: This is the build file I used.
 <target name="deploy">  
  <echo message="Deploying EAR"/>
  <copy todir="${deployDir}/${ant.project.name}">
   <fileset dir="EarContent">
    <include name="**" />
   </fileset>
  </copy>
  <java classname="weblogic.Deployer" append="true">
   <classpath>
    <pathelement location="C:\bea\weblogic92\server\lib\weblogic.jar" />
   </classpath>
   <arg
    line="-adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -username weblogic -password weblogic -redeploy -name ${ant.project.name}" />
  </java>
 </target>

Comment: Actually I can see the output when I run Ant in command prompt. But the output does not show up when it is run in Eclipse

Comment: So it's an Eclipse issue then? When you say "run in Eclipse", are you executing the Ant target in Eclipse or are you just running the app from Eclipse? Depending on how you created your project, Eclipse may not necessarily use your build file. Also, if you *are* executing the Ant via Eclipse, do you see the echo message in your Eclipse's console view?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the [`output`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) attribute of the `java` task. This will redirect your error and output streams to the file specified as the value of this attribute.

Comment: This **specifically** does not solve the question, as it will cause output to go into a file, not to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you used `spawn="true"` (Not to be confused with `fork="true"`, see [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html))?